# What does ウリ mean

Tags: words

What does ウリ mean in the following conversation? Where ソウ and [アムロ＝レイ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4) are two characters in the [[第]{だい}4[次]{じ}スーパーロボット[大戦]{たいせん}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC4%E6%AC%A1%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E5%A4%A7%E6%88%A6).

> ソウ「よろしくお[願]{ねが}いします！アムロ＝レイ[少佐]{しょうさ}」
>
> アムロ「そんなにカタ[苦]{くる}しくしないでいい。ロンド＝ベルは[自由]{じゆう}なのが**ウリ**だ。オレの[事]{こと}もさんづけだけでいい、ソウ[少尉]{しょうい}」
>
> ソウ「じゃ、オレもソウでいいです。」
>
> アムロ「わかったよ、ソウ。じゃ、デスクワークもひと[区切]{くぎ}りついたし、[他]{た}のみんなにも[しょうかい]{しょうかい}しておこうか」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's #1 or #2 of the explanation here:

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%A3%B2%E3%82%8A&ref=sa,

i.e. "sales point" or "big appeal".

As for why it's written in katakana, it's a stylistic choice, and I can only guess about the reason. One reason could be that this meaning of 売り is a bit colloquial.

Comment: I understand that sentence now, means something like "Being casual or freedom is what the ロンド＝ベル team is all about!" Thank you @dainichi さん!